# How to clone a Joomla module?

Tags: php, joomla

I am creating a website with Sobi2 and a sobi2 clone called Marketplace for two different types of listings. In the Sobi2 listing pages I am using a Sobi2 category module for displaying the categories. Now I need to display the market place categories in the marketplace listing pages. So I am planning to clone the module. Please let me know what all changes I need to make to display the cloned module in module manager. I mean which all database tabled I need to alter.

Regards,
Alwin

Comment: Have you tried looking at the database and the code inside the module? Would give you a better idea on what and where to change; then if you get stuck you can ask a detailed question that'll make easier for people to help you without having to code an entire module for you :)

Answer (score 0):

You won't be editing the database. You'll probably be doing a search and replace for `s/Sobi2/Marketplace/g` within the module code, zipping that up, and installing that as a separate module. You'll also need to change the name (mod_XXX) so it's unique.